# Error when updating ppx_sexp_conv to development version using opam

Tags: ocaml, opam

I'm trying to update the ppx_sexp_conv package to version [114.29+06](https://github.com/janestreet/opam-repository/tree/master/packages/ppx_sexp_conv.114.29%2B06). The current version on my system is 113.33.01+4.03. I'm using OCaml 4.03. When I try

`opam pin add ppx_sexp_conv.114.29+06 http://github.com/janestreet/ppx_sexp_conv#94330f2517400a0d520f332726c1bed61b808659`followed by `opam update`

I get the error `[ERROR] ppx_sexp_conv.114.29+06 is not available because your system doesn't comply with ocaml-version = "4.02.3"`

Considering I'm using version 4.03 of OCaml. Could someone please explain what causes this error?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're misreading the message. The message says that the package `ppx_sexp_conv.114.29+06` works with version `4.02.3` no more, no less. Your version is `4.03`, and `4.03 != 4.02.3`.

If you really want this version, then you may try to install the older 4.02.3 version of the compiler.